# Sending notifications to users from other users dependent on certain conditions

Tags: nodes, users, notifications

Is there a way to alert users of the content in a node field? I'm trying to get users to be able to mass message other users based on certain taxonomy terms they're selecting as part of their login process.

So essentially the process (as I'm envisioning it, but I'm open to other methods) would work like this:

User1 selects a county as part of their profile creation.

User2 wants to send an alert to all users that are signed up to that county.

They create a node with the content type, "Alert", which consists of the title, the actual alert information (a text field), and a county.

This is then sent to all users (i.e. user1) with that county.

My guess would be to use the notification and messages modules, and have a user subscribe to a given taxonomy term(s). I'm only seeing how to send messages on content update/creation though, not the actual content of the node.

Are there any solutions for this problem (one to many communication between users dependent on certain criteria)

Answer (score 0):

I put a hierarchical taxonomy term in a user profile, and then had rules send to any user with that county selected.